# What would be the best way to scrape this website? (Not Selenium)

Tags: python, web-scraping

**Before I begin TLDR is at the bottom**

So I'm trying to scrape https://rarbgmirror.com/ for torrent magnet links and for their torrent title names based on user inputted searches. I've already figured out how to do this using BeautifulSoup and Requests through this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

query = input("Input a search: ")
link = 'https://rarbgmirror.com/torrents.php?search=' + query

magnets = []
titles = []
try:
    request = requests.get(link)
except:
    print("ERROR")
source = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for page_link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^/torrent/")}):
    page_link = 'https://www.1377x.to/' + page_link.get('href')
    try:
        page_request = requests.get(page_link)
    except:
        print("ERROR")

    page_source = page_request.content
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
    link = page_soup.find('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^magnet")})
    magnets.append(link.get('href'))
    title = page_soup.find('h1')
    titles.append(title)

print(titles)
print(magnets)
```

I am almost certain that this code has no error in it because the code was originally made for https://1377x.to for the same purpose, and if you look through the HTML structure of both websites, they use the same tags for magnet links and title names. But if the code is faulty please point that out to me!

After some research I found the issue to be that https://rarbgmirror.com/ uses JavaScript which dynamically loads web pages. So after some more research I find that selenium is recommended for this purpose. Well after some time using selenium I find some cons to using it such as:

- The slow speed of scraping
- The system which the app is running on must have the selenium browser installed (I'm planning on using pyinstaller to pack the app which would be an issue)

So I'm requesting for an alternative to selenium to scrape dynamically loaded web pages.

**TLDR**:
I want an alternative to selenium to scrape a website which is dynamically loaded using JavaScript.

**PS: GitHub Repo**:
https://github.com/eliasbenb/MagnetMagnet

Comment: You want to scrape a dynamic site without a browser automater and then package that (Python) app as a desktop app using pyinstaller and distribute? Why do people do this to themselves? Do you enjoy tears?

Comment: @Neil https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y9r_pZL4boE

Comment: Would it make it easier to achieve this if I pack the app using something other than pyinstaller?

Comment: firstly, you probably shouldn't even be packaging it at all. Web scraping relies on the structure of third party sites, which can and do change without notice. usually if you want to scrape a site, you write the script, run it, save the data somewhere and move on to the next thing. You DEFINITELY don't want to distribute a scraper to other people. It can break at any second if the website maintainer changes something and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Secondly, yes, I would avoid pyinstaller or anything that makes Python executables unless you really know what you're doing. Python's desktop environment infrastructure is not very mature at all. I forget how pyinstaller in particular works, but I think they all work by freezing the whole of Python just to run your one little script. And they are a nightmare when things go wrong. If you want to package to share with other devs, use things like docker, virtualenv, pypi etc. If you need an app for end users, make a web app. Desktop with Python is DIFFICULT.

Comment: Finally, web scraping is usually a mission. You're trying to encode the structure of a website, and 90% of websites are html "soup". browser automaters are a powerful tool to tackle this problem. They aren't always necessary, but they can be very helpful. I would be very hesitant of picking a solution that rules out the use of selenium.

Comment: Note that it is entirely possible to run selenium with a browser in headless mode, which will allow you to execute the script on a server.

Comment: OK. Thank you @Neil for the suggestions. I guess I'll make the app without the thought packaging it, and if it is package able at the end then great, if not then too bad, but not a big issue.

So I'll be trying to use Selenium (which I'm not really confident with but will try my best) Thank you again! Have a great day!

Comment: I just read your final comment, does running it on a server mean the user doesn't need to have the specified browser installed?

Comment: If you run the browser on the server with the script, then you can send the results to users who don't have the browser... Not sure who your users are or what the architecture is. But that's probably a different question.

Comment: You can package it with chromium but that might not be a great option. Also there's phantomjs which is now deprecated but still works most of the time.

Comment: The argument that "something changes and your app breaks" is true for both scraping a website and REST APIs. Sure it's almost always _better_ to use an API, but and API doesn't have to even exist, leaving no actual choice.

If you use something like a `jsdom` alternative for Python to parse the returned HTML, with the right `querySelector` you will consistently get the data you want. The actual problem you'll likely face is the website seeing your scrapes and returning some sort of a CAPTCHA and that's where it falls apart. As long as that doesn't happen, scrape as you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WORKING SOLUTION**
DISCLAIMER FOR PEOPLE LOOKING FOR AN ANSWER: this method WILL NOT work for any website other than RARBG

I posted this same question to reddit's r/learnpython someone on there found a great answer which met all my requirements. You can find the original comment [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/fpw6dy/how_would_i_scrape_a_website_which_uses/flnry8y?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x/)

What he found out was that rarbg gets its info from [here](https://torrentapi.org/pubapi_v2.php?mode=search&search_string=QUERY&token=lnjzy73ucv&format=json_extended&app_id=lol)

You can change what is searcher by changing "QUERY" in the link. On that page was all the information for each torrent, so using requests and bs4 I scraped all the information.

Here is the working code:

```
query = input("Input a search: ")
rarbg_link = 'https://torrentapi.org/pubapi_v2.php?mode=search&search_string=' + query + '&token=lnjzy73ucv&format=json_extended&app_id=lol'
try:
    request = requests.get(rarbg_link, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
except:
    print("ERROR")
source = request.text
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml'))
soup = soup.replace('<html><body><p>{"torrent_results":[', '')
soup = soup.split(',')
titles = str([i for i in soup if i.startswith('{"title":')])
titles = titles.replace('{"title":"', '')
titles = titles.replace('"', '')
titles = titles.split("', '")
for title in titles:
    title.append(titles)
    links = str([i for i in soup if i.startswith('"download":')])
    links = links.replace('"download":"', '')
    links = links.replace('"', '')
    links = links.split("', '")
    for link in links:
        magnets.append(link)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using only Chrome, you can check out [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) by Google. It is fast and integrates quite well with Chrome DevTools.

Comment: So from what I can tell this is a Node app? Unfortunately I have 0 experience in Node. I'm currently developing my coding skills starting with python (I've been using python for maybe a month)

Comment: Javascript is a scripting language and not that hard to pick up.

Comment: There's a Python port called Pyppeteer but you probably won't find it much easier because it uses asyncio